# short dashed line length in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a horizontal line in a diagram with the following terminal set in gnuplot:

```
    set terminal postscript eps size 8.5cm, 7cm enhanced color font 'Helvetica,10'
    set style line 5 lt 2 lc rgb "black" lw 3
    f(x)=5.0
    plot f(x) w l ls 5
```

The line width is ok, but the length of the dashes are too short. How can I increase it without changing the terminal mode to dashed line?

Answer (score 6):

For the postscript terminal the default mode is already `dashed`, which you see when you type your `set terminal` line in the interactive gnuplot-terminal:

```
gnuplot> set terminal postscript eps size 8.5cm, 7cm enhanced color font 'Helvetica,10'
Terminal type set to 'postscript'
Options are 'eps enhanced defaultplex \
   leveldefault color colortext \
   dashed dashlength 1.0 linewidth 1.0 butt noclip \
   nobackground \
   palfuncparam 2000,0.003 \
   size 8.50cm, 7.00cm "Helvetica" 10  fontscale 1.0 '
```

Otherwise, in `solid` mode, the only dashed linetype is `lt -1`.

The above message also tells you, how you can change the dashlength. Up to version 4.6, the only way to change the dashlength is to use the `dashlength` option, e.g. with

```
set termoption dashlength 1.5
```

Unfortunately, this affects all line types.

Only 5.0 version supports arbitrary, configurable dash patterns. Note also, that in version 5 the dashlength depends on the selected line width.

Answer (score 3):

I have used this and the results are not bad for me, (gnuplot 4.2):

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced color dl 2.0 font 'TimesRoman' 24
```

Here, by changing `dl 2.0` to `dl 3.0`, you can get larger dash lines.